# Repeating actions using Alarm in Android background service

Tags: java, android

I wrote this code in MainService.java that is called in foreground by using startForeground method. I want to make a toast message in every 10 seconds but it doesn't work. How can I fix it??

```
public void Alarm(){
        Intent intent = new Intent("AlarmService");
        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 10 * 1000;
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                am.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, sender) ;
            } else {
                am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, sender);
            }
        } else {
            am.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, firstTime, sender);
        }
    }

    BroadcastReceiver alarmReceiver;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        alarmReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub\
                count++;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),count+"times",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                Alarm();
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, new IntentFilter("AlarmService"));
    }
```

Comment: You don't call `.show()` on your `Toast`.

Comment: see @YooMinjun, keep in mind oreo restriction, you can't fire repeating alarm in that quick interval

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager to do Background tasks